# ssh script commands lost after exiting nested shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, terminal

I am executing a script through ssh like this:

`ssh $USER@somehost 'bash -s' < ./myscript.sh`

inside `myscript.sh`:

```
echo '1'
sudo -i -u svcacct   # use the service account
echo '2'
exit                 # last working command
echo '3'             
exit
echo '4'
```

Output:

```
shellA$ 1
shellB$ 2
shellA$
```

As you can see, the `exit` command, while properly exiting the inner session, prevents the subsequent script commands from running.  The ssh connection hangs (Ctrl-C exits).  How do I fix this?

Comment: There are several ways this can go wrong, but one of the easiest ones is for the inner bash started by `sudo -i` (which is told that it's interactive, and thus presumably has a real TTY with a keyboard to itself) to read beyond the `exit`, even if the `exit` is the last command it *executes*. If it's consumed the `echo '4'` line of input, that input isn't available for any other process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working implementation, emitting `1`, `2` and `3`, would look like:

```
echo '1'
sudo -u svcacct -i bash -s <<'EOF-1'
echo '2'
EOF-1
echo '3'             
exit
echo '4'
```

Note that we're **not** depending on any program to exit leaving the file descriptor for stdin with any particular content queued-up to be read, but instead are providing the `svcacct` instance with only a very limited and specific subset of stdin from a distinct heredoc.